# ASP.NET boolean variable

Tags: asp.net, boolean

I've been looking at some source code for an ASP.NET page and stumbled across

`booLockAll=(booLockAll==false);`

I've never seen a variable declared like this in any other language. 
Is this unique for ASP.NET? 
Is this just wrong?

Why would you not write it:
`booLockAll==false`

Comment: Can you give us a little more context, is this in the code behind file? Where is booLockAll defined (there's no bool or var there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a declaration. It's an assignment statement whose effect is inverting the variable's value.

```
booLockAll is false => (booLockAll==false) yields true
booLockAll is true  => (booLockAll==false) yields false
```

Easier and a lot more readable would be to use `booLockAll = !booLockAll;`.

Comment: Awesome, I've just never seen it written like this.

Answer (score 0):

That's just invert of a bool variable, just like

```
booLockAll = !booLockAll
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is used to change the value of booLockAll.

Sample code that does the same

```
if(booLockAll==false)
{
   booLockAll = true;
}
else
{
   booLockAll = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That means if previous value of `booLockAll` was `false` then new value will be `true` or if previous one was `true` then new one will be `false`.